# RazorSql convert MySQL ddl to HyperSQL - generated DDL doesn't run on HSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, hsqldb, razorsql

I used RazorSQL to convert my MySQL database tables to HQL - generating a DDL file.

When examine the DDL file it looks fine:

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
    Person_Id INTEGER IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Person_Id)
);
```

But i had to change the SQL for it to work against HSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
    Person_Id INTEGER generated by default as identity (start with 1),
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Person_Id)
);
```

I don't want to change the SQL everytime after conversion.

Comment: Both scripts are reported incorrectly. There is no `Class_Id` column in the table.

Comment: edited. due to copy n paste typo